# Interactive option for function with optional arguments

Tags: interactive, arguments

Am unsure whether making `brcmk-end` optional is possible for interactive use.  If one can have optional arguments, what would be the changed necessary?  Would the interactive expression change?

```lisp
    (defun rk-bracemk-count-2 (brcmk-beg brcmk-end rgn-beg rgn-end)
      "Count brace marks within a selected region.
    
    BRCMK-BEG  Opening brace mark.
    BRCMK-END  Closing brace mark.
    RGN-BEG    Region start marker or position.
    RGN-END    Region end marker or position."
    
      (interactive
       (list (read-char-from-minibuffer "Opening bracemark: ")
             (read-char-from-minibuffer "Closing bracemark: ")
             (region-beginning)
             (region-end) ))
      
      (save-excursion
        (let ( ($a  0) ($b  0) 
               ($begmk  (char-to-string brcmk-beg))
               ($endmk  (char-to-string brcmk-end)) )
    
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) rgn-end)
                      (search-forward $begmk rgn-end t))
            (cl-incf $a))
    
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) rgn-end)
                      (search-forward $endmk rgn-end t))
            (cl-incf $b))
    
          (message "Marks: %s %s  Counts: %d %d" $begmk $endmk $a $b)
          (goto-char rgn-beg) )))
```

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using `(interactive "cOpening bracemark: \ncClosing bracemark: \nr")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any of the args after the first *N* (*N*=0...) args optional. The first *N* are required (but if *N* is zero then none are required).

The `interactive` spec need only provide the required args. It can of course provide some or all of the other args, as well.

If a caller of the function, or if the `interactive` spec, does not provide some optional arg then its value is `nil`.

If the body of the function needs a non-`nil` value for such an omitted optional arg then the body has to provide that itself (e.g. change the value from `nil` to something else, if needed).

In your command, if you make `brcmk-end` optional then your `interactive` spec can remain as it is, because it provides a reasonable value for that argument.  If youre `interactive` spec did not read or otherwise provide that arg then when the body tried to evaluate `(char-to-string brcmk-end)` an error would be raised.

Comment: Does it make sense to have the beginning and end region (`rgn-beg`, `rgn-end`) be optional ?

Comment: How can one avoid the error trying to evaluate `(char-to-string brcmk-end)` ?

Comment: 1. Whatever you want to do "makes sense". 2. In `interactive` you already avoid the error. In Lisp code the caller needs to provide `brcmk-end` as a character.

Comment: In lisp code, I also want for `brcmk-end` to be optional.

Comment: If I put `brcmk-end` as optional, would `rgn-beg` and `rgn-end` have to be optional as well when `brcmk-end` is set to optional?  Would like to keep `brcmk-end` to follow `brcmk-beg`; and `rgn-end` to follow `rgn-beg`.

Comment: Yes. That's what this says: *"You can make any of the args after the first N (N=0...) args optional. The first N are required (but if N is zero then none are required)."* You really should consult the Emacs documentation and help. You're not doing yourself any favors by guessing. In the Elisp manual, `i optional TAB` gives you index entry `optional arguments`, and that takes you directly to the relevant [Argument List](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html) doc.

Comment: If you want some args to be required and others optional, reorder them accordingly.

Comment: The addition of optional complicates things a bit.  Will spend some time thinking about this and read more as you say.